# Trying to intent from Normal Activity to fragment and crash

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've created Sign in activity and signup.
after that i created Fragment list of view and each one is working fine
when i try to sign in it crash.

here is the error :

```
02-28 09:27:55.969    1662-1675/com.example.asro9.englishcapsules3 E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xee979760
02-28 09:28:27.532    1662-1662/com.example.asro9.englishcapsules3 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-28 09:28:27.532    1662-1662/com.example.asro9.englishcapsules3 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.asro9.englishcapsules3, PID: 1662
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.asro9.englishcapsules3/com.example.asro9.englishcapsules3.Fragment1}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1794)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1512)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3917)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4200)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4168)
            at com.example.asro9.englishcapsules3.SignUPActivity$1.onClick(SignUPActivity.java:73)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Sign Up code for the Java Act

```
package com.example.asro9.englishcapsules3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by asro9 on 2/20/2016.
 */
public class SignUPActivity extends Activity
{
    EditText editTextFirstName,editTextSecondName,editTextLastName,editTextPhoneNumber,editTextAddress,
            editTextUserName,editTextPassword,editTextConfirmPassword;;
    Button btnCreateAccount;

    LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signup);

        // get Instance  of Database Adapter
        loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
        loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

        // Get Refferences of Views
        editTextUserName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
        editTextPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        editTextConfirmPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextConfirmPassword);
        editTextFirstName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.FirstName);
        editTextSecondName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.SecondName);
        editTextLastName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.LastName);
        editTextPhoneNumber=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.PhoneNumber);
        editTextAddress=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Address);

        btnCreateAccount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCreateAccount);
        btnCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String Firstname = editTextFirstName.getText().toString();
                String SeconedName = editTextSecondName.getText().toString();
                String LastName = editTextLastName.getText().toString();
                String Phone = editTextPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
                String Address = editTextAddress.getText().toString();
                String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                String confirmPassword=editTextConfirmPassword.getText().toString();

                // check if any of the fields are vaccant
                if (userName.equals("")||password.equals("")|| confirmPassword.equals("") || Firstname.equals("") || SeconedName.equals("") || LastName.equals("") || Phone.equals("") || Address.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field Vaccant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                // check if both password matches
                if(!password.equals(confirmPassword))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Save the Data in Database
                    loginDataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(userName, password);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SignUPActivity.this,Fragment1.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();

        loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
    }
}
```

Fragment that i wanted to navigate to :

```
    package com.example.asro9.englishcapsules3;/**
 * Created by NgocTri on 10/18/2015.
 */

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    ListView myList;
    ArrayList<String> Title = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter;
    ArrayList<Integer> images = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    LazyAdapter myLazyAdapter;
    LazyAdapter myLazyTitle;

    public Fragment1() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

        myList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        Title.add("Amer At English Capsules");
        Title.add("El Fayoum Trip From Capsules");
        Title.add("Bla bla bla");
        Title.add("Title");
        Title.add("Title");

        images.add(R.drawable.fen);
        images.add(R.drawable.cover);
        images.add(R.drawable.sdsd);
        images.add(R.drawable.speaking);
        images.add(R.drawable.fen);
        images.add(R.drawable.cover);
        images.add(R.drawable.sdsd);
        images.add(R.drawable.speaking);
        images.add(R.drawable.fen);
        images.add(R.drawable.cover);
        images.add(R.drawable.sdsd);
        images.add(R.drawable.speaking);
        images.add(R.drawable.cover);
        images.add(R.drawable.cover);
        images.add(R.drawable.cover);
        images.add(R.drawable.cover);
        images.add(R.drawable.cover);


        myLazyAdapter = new LazyAdapter(getActivity(),images);
        myList.setAdapter(myLazyAdapter);

        return rootView;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to switch a fragment like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SignUPActivity.this,Fragment1.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

This is not correct because Fragment1 is not an activitiy so this is raising the error you reported:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.asro9.englishcapsules3/com.example.asro9.englishcapsules3.Fragment1}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

I suggest to take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions) and [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) to check some of the fragments principles.

If your goal was to switch fragments once the user was logged successfully then there is no need to start a new activity but to perform a fragment switch. However you can take also the second approach and start a new activity instead. But that depends on you.

Comment: it's an app and after the use login it go to the slide menu and switch to main activites i got for the slide menu as frgament 1 , fragment 2 , fragment 3 for the slide menu activies and the sign in , with the sign up and the custom list of view on the fragment 1 work fine without the slide menu when i try to mirage between all it appear the  and when im trying to delare the fragment activites on the Manifest i can't do it !